# Update java desktop app

Tags: java, desktop-application, executable-jar, auto-update

I am trying to develop a module that can update my running Java Desktop App.
The problem is that I have to replace the actual running jar with another jar, all the while displaying an image and a progress bar with the remaining time of the update process.

One solution I thought about is that I can put a jar in my main jar, and when launching the update process, to extract that second jar which will display the image and the progess bar, and also which will replace the old main jar with a new main jar.
My question is if this is possible and how can I do it.
I do not have a lot of experience with java and java packaging so if you have any examples or links, it would be of great help for me.

Thank you very much.
R.

Comment: Be sure to let us know if you are successful or not

Comment: Are you sure it makes sense to update your "main UI" without stopping the application? I once created a huge application that would support a number of plugins; and each of this plugins could be updated "on the fly". But in order to update your "main UI" ... you will have to "stop it" anyway (as you will have to discard the class loader that you used to load the JAR contents). Meaning: the user will experience an "outage" anyway; so why all the effort to unload a JAR, load a new one (with progress bar)? It would be much easier to just stop the application and have an independent "upgrade app".

Comment: You could think about some kind of "launcher"-application that starts the main app. The launcher can update the main app, before starting it.

Comment: The idea is that the inner jar has to be extracted from the main jar, the main jar will stop running, and the inner jar will display the progress bar and the image. Also the inner jar will replace the main jar(copy a new jar from another location over the main jar) and after that it will launch the new main jar and exit.Hard to implement. I have to extract the inner jar while the main jar is running. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Run this code when press **UPDATE** button ..

```
       if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("update.jar"));
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (IOException ex) {                
            }            
        }
```

This will open **update.jar** and close **main.jar**. Now run this code from main class of **update.jar**

```
           //wait sometime for terminate main.jar

           try{
              Thread.sleep(5000);
           } catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
    

        if(isUpdateVersionAvailable()) { //first check update from database
          
           if(copyMainJarFileFromServer()){ //copy newMain.jar from server and paste
              new File("main.jar").delete(); //delete main.jar                  
              rename(new File("newMain.jar")); //rename newMain.jar to main.jar
            }
        }
            
        boolean isUpdateVersionAvailable() {
                  //todo
        }
        boolean copyMainJarFileFromServer() {
                  //todo
        }
        void rename(File file){
         file.renameTo(new File("main.jar"));
        }
```

Comment: You need to wait update.jar until terminate main.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can have a starter jar that checks for updates and launches the app from the main jar.

It will show start logo, an image, that standard java can display at start-up.
The start0er could also be used to restart the app in another interface language.

```
package starter;
...
public class StarterApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String workDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        Path mainJar = Paths.get(workDir + "...");
        Path nextMainJar = Paths.get(workDir + "...");
        if (Files.exists(nextMainJar)) {
            Files.copy(nextMainJar, mainJar, StandardCopyAction.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {mainJar.toURL()});
        Class<?> appClass = classLoader.find("mainjar.MainApp");
        ... instantiate the app
    }
```

As you see the main jar must not be loaded from too early, maybe not be on the class path entirely, and hence the use of a separate ClassLoader. The same might probably be done with the main jar *on* the class path of the starter app, and using `Class.forName("mainjar.MainApp")`. The Class-Path can be specified in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

The secundary jars may reside in a lib/ directory.

For those readers wanting more modular, service oriented, updateable apps, one could make an **OSGi** application, a container for bundles (=jars), that provide exchangable services and life-time control.